# Batch / multiple iOS Push Notification code - works for 2 devices, but not for 100

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The following code works fine if the number of devices I send to is 2 - i.e., they both receive the push notifications. But if I raise that limit to 100, no push notifications are received.

I have read up on this and it looks like I am sending the batch notifications correctly (i.e., multiple requests via a single connection); the timeout of the connection is set nice and high (60 seconds); the output of the code all looks in order; nothing in the apache error log, so I don't see where the problem is.

My customer's getting really hacked off. Can anyone help??

function sendIosPushes() {

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => pushMessage, 'badge' => badgeNumber, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($payload);

//$statement = "SELECT * FROM push_ios WHERE device_token = 'device token of my iphone" OR device_token = 'device token of my ipod'; //works selecting my two devices from table
$statement = "SELECT * FROM push_ios"; //doesn't work when selecting all devices from table


$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', apnsCert);

$connectTimeout = 60;
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . apnsHost . ':' . apnsPort, $error, $errorString, $connectTimeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);

$numDevices = 0;
$numRequestsSent = 0;
$result = mysql_query($statement);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $numDevices++;
    try {
        $deviceToken = $row['device_token'];

        //$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload; //from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642411/sending-multiple-iphone-notifications

        $fwriteRes = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage, strlen($apnsMessage));
        echo "Push sent to " . $deviceToken . "<br />\n";

        $numRequestsSent++;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "1. Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
    }
}

fclose($apns);


if ($error != 0 || (isset($errorString) && strlen($errorString) > 0 )) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $error . " - ". $errorString . "<br />\n";
}

return $numDevices . " iOS devices. " . $numRequestsSent . " requests sent.";
```

}

Comment: You probably have some invalid device tokens in your DB. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112151/how-to-properly-send-push-notifications/17113699#17113699).

Comment: @Eran, thanks. I don't think there are any invalid tokens in my db table, because I call the APNS Feedback Service right before the above code is called to remove the bad tokens from my db table. Also, for each push request (whether I'm sending to 2 or 100 devices), the value returned to $fwriteRes is 104 - which indicates APNS is receiving the requests, right? Also, I get no error back from APNS. Do you think the APNS could be failing sliently?

Comment: 1. The Feedback service has nothing to do with invalid device tokens (it only returns valid tokens of devices from which your app was uninstalled). 2. I don't know what returns this 104 value or what it means. Apple don't return anything when they receive the request successfully. 3. In case of an invalid device token, Apple will return an error response if you use the newer binary format (in which you send a message id and message expiry), which you don't. In your case an invalid token will simply close the socket, but you'll have no way to know which message caused the problem.

Comment: The value returned from fwrite() - 104 - is the number of bytes written, which indicates the socket isn't closed as fwrite() returns FALSE on error. Would you agree, then, that there is a silent failure going on within APNS? If the only way I can tell which tokens are messing things up is to use the newer binary format, can you point me in the right direction (pref. with some code examples)?

Comment: `It can take a while for the dropped connection to make its way from APNs back to your server just because of normal latency. It's possible to send over 500 notifications before a write fails because of the connection being dropped` You should read about error checking [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html). I don't have code samples. You should read about the format [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4).

Comment: @Eran, it's all sorted!! It was the very first device in the table that was the dud. I amended my code to skip that device. I then made sure that my two devices were first and last in the table, then sent another push notification - and it came through on both devices. Thank you so much for your help. :) Do you want to add a quick answer to this question so I can formerly accept it.

Comment: Incidentally, I have have twice tried adding the tag 'batch' to my question, but each time it got automatically changed to 'batch-file' - why is that??

Comment: Glad I could help. I added an answer.

Comment: Regarding your last question - the `batch` tag is a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/synonyms) to `batch-file`. That's why it's automatically changed.

Comment: @Eran, for anyone else having this problem, regarding the delays in detecting the dropped connection making it so difficult to find the problematic device token, if a sleep (maybe for 1 second) was introduced in the loop so there was a delay between writing each request, maybe that would result in the connection being closed at the most helpful point? (Just mentioning this as it may help someone else.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have some invalid device tokens in your DB.

In case of an invalid device token, Apple will return an error response if you use the newer binary format (in which you send a message id and message expiry), which you don't. In your case an invalid token will simply close the socket, but you'll have no way to know which message caused the problem.

You should read about error checking [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html). You should read about the format [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4).

Comment: (As mentioned in the comments, I found the problematic device tokens fairly easily as it was the very first device token in the db table (presumably one that was used for sandbox testing).